# SQL Get percent of bad records from total

Tags: sql

i am relatively new to SQL. Each employee access an account for testing with a tech, sometimes it's a good attempt, sometimes it's bad, so I need to calculate the percentage of the bad attempts mostly, my report should look something like this:

SELECT 
employee, event, total, percentage
FROM my_table

```
employee |  event |  total |  percentage|
user1    |  good  |   50   |    50%     |
user1    |  bad   |   50   |    50%     |
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: what is your actual question? based on your example you already have the percentages as a separate column.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. Not just expected output. Also the db schema
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the total in a subquery and then `JOIN` to calculate percentage on each row.

```
SELECT employee, event, COUNT(*),  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / t.total as percentage
FROM my_table
JOIN (SELECT employee, count(*) total
      FROM my_table
      GROUP BY employee) T
  ON my_table.employee = t.employee
GROUP BY employee, event
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it! Thank you so much and I am sorry for my horrible first question. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Remember accet the answer if solve your problem. And upvote when you have the privelege

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this calculate the `bad` event percentage for each employee

```
select employee,(sum(case when event = 'bad' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) * 100
From Yourtable
Group by employee
```

Comment: i got this error while doing this "Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator."